# Can I get the CPU temperature and fan speed from the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, temperature, command-line, monitoring

Is there a command I can run from the command line in OS X to get the current CPU temperature and/or the fan speed(s)?

To be more specific, I'd like to be able to get the same info available in the [iStat widget](http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatnano/) under the Fans and Temps tabs on the command line.

I'd like to be able to find these values at the command line so it could be scripted and plugged into a monitoring setup on my Mac - I have a data-nerd desire to collect and graph these values (and other stats) on my Macbook over time.

On Linux, it seems like this would be possible by reading a pseudo-file under the `/proc` directory, but I'm not sure how to do the equivalent on OS X (if it exists).

Comment: I don't know about built-in, but iStat Menus is a menu bar app that includes that info. iStat Nano and iStat Pro are dashboard widgets that also include this information.

Comment: 3rd party is the only way to go in this situation

Comment: here is a Terminal + app combo http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54332/46541

Comment: **Simply install [smcFanControl](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/releases) open-source App**, which shows current speed beside clock (beside allowing manual changing).

Comment: To what purpose? What will you do with that data?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

**Option #1)** you may consider using inbuilt utility powermetrics to get the cpu and gpu temperature and lot more other details.

To get CPU temperature:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "CPU die temperature"
```

[image]

To get GPU temperature:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "GPU die temperature"
```

To get lot more details:

```
sudo powermetrics
```

This has been tested on macbook pro with macOS mojave.

**Option #2)**
Install Intel® Power Gadget officially provided by Intel from here

[Intel® Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget/) and then launch Intel Power Gadget from the launchpad.

[image]

Result Screen:

[image]

Comment: The options here are great especially Powermetrics

Comment: You can do `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc -i1 -n1` to get a single instant sample of SMC sensor readings, including CPU and GPU temprature and fan speed.

Comment: powermetrics doesn't list any temperatures for me, on a 2018 MacMini running Mojave.

Comment: @benwiggy you can try sudo powermetrics and see if it return other meaningful info, check powermetrics man page. Or option#2 you can give it a try.

Comment: No, sudo powermetrics doesn't work either. "unable to get smc values" on a Mac Mini.
I don't like the Intel Gadget, as it installs stuff into the system, and it only shows 1 core, weirdly.

Comment: on m1 I'm getting `unrecognized sampler: smc`

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko does ```sudo powermetrics``` works on m1? if so, you can find some other way of limiting sensor reading to count 1.

Comment: Is it possible to make a non-sudo command?

Comment: @JerryGreen Ideally /etc/sudoers file can be modified on unix system to allow specific user to run specific command/all commands without sudo. But updating this needs admin rights. Note: I haven't tested this on mac.

Answer (score 258):

The [iStats ruby gem](https://github.com/Chris911/iStats) lets you see the CPU temperature via the command-line.

#### Installation

`$ gem install iStats`

#### Usage

`$ istats all`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: sudo gem install iStats failed on brand new MBP Mavericks. Error looks like this: http://hastebin.com/lihaqiyeyu.vhdl

Comment: Unfortunately that's a known error. If you take a look at the [Github repo](https://github.com/Chris911/iStats) there's a note about it. You can either install Ruby using RVM or brew or use this command to install the gem instead: `sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install iStats`

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm (nice sparklines too). Just had to do it with "sudo"

Comment: For live updates: `watch -n0 istats` (I had to `brew install watch` on OSX before doing the above) See: http://superuser.com/q/361902

Comment: To get rid of display errors use this: `watch --color istats`.

Comment: Hi Chris, I know nothing about Ruby - what's the full path to iStats?

Comment: Once iStats is installed you should be able to run the `istats` command from any path.

Comment: Worked like a chard in El Capitan.

Comment: second to el capitan working with this command

Comment: You [don't have to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38259128/241211) (and probably shouldn't) use `sudo`. Instead, use `gem install --user-install iStats`

Comment: @Michael I installed it with `gem install --user-install iStats`, but when I try to run `istats`, I have a "command not found" message.

Comment: @darksoulsong Is `/usr/local/bin` part of your `$PATH`?

Comment: it installs but then just says that iStats is not found

Comment: Returning a week after installing to say I use it `istats` command very regularly now. But today I discovered `istats scan`, which gives many more readings still. Thanks for this great gem!

Answer (score 48):

On BSD systems, the `sysctl` utility can provides similar information as the `/proc` tree in Linux. It actually report some CPU/GPU temperature information from [Xnu CPU Power Management](https://pikeralpha.wordpress.com/2013/10/05/xnu-cpu-power-management/) (XCPM):

```
sysctl machdep.xcpm.cpu_thermal_level
sysctl machdep.xcpm.gpu_thermal_level
```

However this doesn't seem to be a temperature reading but only an indication of the temperature level compared to some reference.

Comment: These 2 commands print `machdep.xcpm.cpu_thermal_level: 0` and `machdep.xcpm.gpu_thermal_level: 0` on Macos 10.12

Comment: On 10.13.4 I get what looks like vaguely credible readings (currently `machdep.xcpm.cpu_thermal_level: 58`)

Comment: what are units ? celsius or fahrenheit, I get as an output: machdep.xcpm.cpu_thermal_level: 93

Comment: Yeah. What are the units?\

Comment: These both return 0 for my MBP running the latest macOS (10.15.4).

The stock command-line utility `powermetrics` also shows some "thermal level"s as 0, but happens to also display the CPU/GPU die temperatures which is what I (and I imagine everyone else) actually care about. See [Satish's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372928) and @rjmunro's comment.

Comment: It turns out I spoke too soon, once my temperature went above ~50°C the thermal level started increasing. But I still have no idea what it means.

Comment: Best answer: nothing to install, no sudo required.

Comment: It show instant result, which is good, but how come it is showing different result than  `powermetrics` command?

Answer (score 39):

This open source command line utility worked for me: https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp.

Comment: I thought it will be harder to compile this, but it's not! Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks, Dust! I'm not much for building stuff from scratch but this was easy and works out of the box. M. Lavoie is using code Apple released a while back:  Apple System Management Control (SMC) Tool Copyright (C) 2006 but it works fine on my 2011 Mini.

Comment: `brew install osx-cpu-temp`

Comment: Just so you know, the sensor this uses is the CPU Proximity temperature, which is different from the CPU PECI (overall CPU temperature) and each core's individual temperatures, that are often significantly higher than the CPU Proximity. Macs Fan Control reports CPU Proximity on my Mac as 55ºC, but CPU PECI as 63ºC

Comment: Reports `0.0°C` on mac studio (arm)

Comment: Note that for recent Macs, the fan speed will not wortk: https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp/issues/21

Answer (score 20):

**Update:** [@PressingOnAlways has notified me](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x#comment220723_54332) that this software is now considered legacy by its developer. Further details on the stopped support can be found on [their legacy-software website](http://www.bresink.com/osx/LegacyProducts.html).

Install [Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html) and, assuming you installed it in `/Applications`, run the following:
`/Applications/TemperatureMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/tempmonitor -c -l -a`

You can also use the updated (however no longer in development, but downloadable) [Hardware Monitor](https://www.bresink.com/osx/216202/download.php) from the same author: `/Applications/to/HardwareMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/hwmonitor`

Comment: Thanks for this. I take it if I need to install this third-party app for it, there isn't a known built-in way to do the same?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. I've used that same program to display the values with Geektool for a time but didn't find any information about a built-in tool. Mind you that that was more than a year ago, so there ,ight be now. I doubt it though.

Comment: It would be great if there was a copy of `tempmonitor` on [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: `tempmonitor` does not show fan speed

Comment: Note TemperatureMonitor does not support any Macs made after October 2013, or so it told me when I tried to run it on my MacBookPro Retina.

Comment: As of Oct 1st, Temperature Monitor has been suspended - they went "Pro".

Comment: this no longer is viable as this software is no longer kept up to date.

Comment: the app still works in big sur - even if no longer maintained. just run `/path/to/HardwareMonitor.app/Contents/MacOS/hwmonitor` in terminal

Answer (score 12):

The SMC sampler is not available on the M1 (or on Big Sur, not sure which). You can get frequencies and power usage for CPU and GPU with powermetrics, but not the temperature, as far as I can tell.

The temperature can probably still be read from the SMC, but it looks like the keys changed for the M1, and might even be different between the M1 models.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are two main ways to view your CPU stats if you don‘t want to install additional software you can view a lot of details from the terminal / command line.

1. Type on the terminal...

   ```
   sudo powermetrics
   ```

   And at the bottom you will see the following:

   ```
   **** SMC sensors ****

   CPU Thermal level: 51
   GPU Thermal level: 35
   IO Thermal level: 1
   Fan: 2060 rpm 
   CPU die temperature: 88.36 C (fan) 
   GPU die temperature: 74.38 C 
   CPU Plimit: 0.00 
   GPU Plimit (Int): 0.00  
   GPU2 Plimit (Ext1): 0.00
   ```
2. Or try typing. (But Apple maybe removed the details from this to just numbers 0 or 1?)

   ```
   sysctl -a | grep cpu | more
   ```

   Or thermal / temperature details only?

   ```
   sysctl -a | grep thermal
   ```

   The output should look like this:

   ```
   hw.ncpu: 8
   hw.activecpu: 8
   hw.physicalcpu: 4
   hw.physicalcpu_max: 4
   hw.logicalcpu: 8
   hw.logicalcpu_max: 8
   hw.cputype: 7
   hw.cpusubtype: 8
   hw.cpu64bit_capable: 1
   hw.cpufamily: 280134364
   hw.cpufrequency: 2800000000
   hw.cpufrequency_min: 2800000000
   hw.cpufrequency_max: 2800000000
   hw.cputhreadtype: 1
   machdep.cpu.max_basic: 13
   machdep.cpu.max_ext: 2147483656
   machdep.cpu.vendor: GenuineIntel
   machdep.cpu.brand_string: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
   machdep.cpu.family: 6
   machdep.cpu.model: 70
   machdep.cpu.extmodel: 4
   machdep.cpu.extfamily: 0
   machdep.cpu.stepping: 1
   machdep.cpu.feature_bits: 9221960xxxxxx657855
   machdep.cpu.leaf7_feature_bits: 10155 0
   machdep.cpu.leaf7_feature_bits_edx: 261xxxxxx2
   machdep.cpu.extfeature_bits: 1424xxxxxx52
   machdep.cpu.signature: 263777
   machdep.cpu.brand: 0
   machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX SMX EST TM2 SSSE3 FMA CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1 SSE4.2 x2APIC MOVBE POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE SEGLIM64 TSCTMR AVX1.0 RDRAND F16C
   machdep.cpu.leaf7_features: RDWRFSGS TSC_THREAD_OFFSET BMI1 AVX2 SMEP BMI2 ERMS INVPCID FPU_CSDS MDCLEAR IBRS STIBP L1DF SSBD
   machdep.cpu.extfeatures: SYSCALL XD 1GBPAGE EM64T LAHF LZCNT RDTSCP TSCI
   machdep.cpu.logical_per_package: 16
   machdep.cpu.cores_per_package: 8
   machdep.cpu.microcode_version: 28
   machdep.cpu.processor_flag: 5
   machdep.cpu.mwait.linesize_min: 64
   machdep.cpu.mwait.linesize_max: 64
   machdep.cpu.mwait.extensions: 3
   machdep.cpu.mwait.sub_Cstates: 270624
   machdep.cpu.thermal.sensor: 1
   machdep.cpu.thermal.dynamic_acceleration: 1
   machdep.cpu.thermal.invariant_APIC_timer: 1
   machdep.cpu.thermal.thresholds: 2
   machdep.cpu.thermal.ACNT_MCNT: 1
   machdep.cpu.thermal.core_power_limits: 1
   machdep.cpu.thermal.fine_grain_clock_mod: 1
   machdep.cpu.thermal.package_thermal_intr: 1
   machdep.cpu.thermal.hardware_feedback: 0
   machdep.cpu.thermal.energy_policy: 1
   machdep.cpu.xsave.extended_state: 7 832 832 0
   machdep.cpu.xsave.extended_state1: 1 0 0 0
   machdep.cpu.arch_perf.version: 3
   machdep.cpu.arch_perf.number: 4
   machdep.cpu.arch_perf.width: 48
   machdep.cpu.arch_perf.events_number: 7
   machdep.cpu.arch_perf.events: 0
   machdep.cpu.arch_perf.fixed_number: 3
   machdep.cpu.arch_perf.fixed_width: 48
   machdep.cpu.cache.linesize: 64
   machdep.cpu.cache.L2_associativity: 8
   machdep.cpu.cache.size: 256
   machdep.cpu.tlb.inst.large: 8
   machdep.cpu.tlb.data.small: 64
   machdep.cpu.tlb.data.small_level1: 64
   machdep.cpu.tlb.shared: 1024
   machdep.cpu.address_bits.physical: 39
   machdep.cpu.address_bits.virtual: 48
   machdep.cpu.core_count: 4
   machdep.cpu.thread_count: 8
   machdep.cpu.tsc_ccc.numerator: 0
   machdep.cpu.tsc_ccc.denominator: 0
   machdep.xcpm.cpu_thermal_level: 0
   ```

   You will notice the frequency details and also some thermal info. You can also `grep thermal` if you are only interested in that.

Comment: I would love it if sysctl actually showed the temperature, it would be so easy, fast and integrated... but it reports only 0 or 1 on a 2014 Mac Mini running the latest macOS Mojave

Answer (score 4):

OS X does not offer this functionality. smcFanControl and the iStat widgets are the typical go-to choices for this issue. I personally use smcFanControl. It gives me both the temperature and the ability to monitor fan operation.

Comment: NOTE: iStat Pro isn't available from Bjango any more, but [this MacRumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/istat-pro-replacement.1407448/) has download links for patched versions. You may have to scroll around a bit to find the most recent version, but it's free (always has been, no piracy here) and IMO is overall better than Menus even though it's not supported.

Answer (score 2):

The tool `osx-cpu-temp` works perfectly for me ! (thanks)
I made a little script to actuate the value each second and to prettify the output (it uses `toilet` for the pretty-output) :

```sh
while true; do; clear; osx-cpu-temp | toilet -f smblock; sleep 1; done;
```

Using ITerm2, I made a profile that lauches this command just after logging. ITerm2 can also store a window arrangement, so I stored one with `tty-clock`, `htop` and my command (named it `cpu-temp`) sized like a status bar, with very small font.

Answer (score 1):

The smc values for [temperature sensors are accessible via ObjectiveC](https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp/blob/master/smc.c) with swift bindings and several python libraries and packages take advantage of this to make it easy to pull values.

https://github.com/nicolargo/glances

This one on python has auto-update && colors built-in and can be installed with a simple curl or wget command if requirements are already met.

Requirements

- python >= 2.6 or >= 3.3 (tested with version 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4)
- psutil >= 2.0.0
- setuptools

Comment: This answer works very well with modern os in the fall of 2022

Comment: Why not just brew install glances?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to improve **option #1** from [Satish's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372928/32815) to display information related to the SMC sensors:

`sudo powermetrics | sed -n '/\*\*\*\* SMC sensors \*\*\*\*/,/Number of prochots/p'`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is possible without *any* external tools, but if you're looking for something small/lightweight (and open source) I highly recommend [Stats](https://github.com/exelban/stats).

It includes a commandline tool, at `/Applications/Stats.app/Contents/Resources/smc` which can be symlinked to `/usr/local/bin` for convenience.

E.g to list all temps/sensors:

```
smc list -t
```

Answer (score 0):

On my mid-2011 MacMini with OSX 10.13.6 I use `smc` to set and check the fan speed plus `osx-cpu-temp` for the temperature.

https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl

https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp

Answer (score 0):

Another new CLI tool that does this very well is iSMC: https://github.com/dkorunic/iSMC

Here's a screenshot of some of the output:
[image]

It doesn't show eGPU temperature, but that info exists in `ioreg` somewhere.  You can extract some stats about your GPU/eGPU manually from ioreg with this:

```sh
ioreg -l | grep '"PerformanceStatistics"' | sed -E "s/,/\\n/g;s/\"//g" | grep -E "(temp|power|Device Utilization|Fan|speed|GPU Activity)"
```

If you have multiple GPUs their stats will be mixed. I select just my Vega 56 eGPU like this:

```sh
ioreg -c AMDRadeonX5000_AMDVega10GraphicsAccelerator -r -l | grep '"PerformanceStatistics"' | sed -E "s/,/\\n/g;s/\"//g" | grep -E "(temp|power|Device Utilization|Fan|speed|GPU Activity)"

...

Device Utilization %=7
Fan Speed(%)=0
GPU Activity(%)=16
Fan Speed(RPM)=0
Temperature(C)=36
Total Power(W)=35
```