# Using terminal to get current fan speed?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos, bash

I would like to view the current fan speeds of my MacBook and iMac using terminal. I've found that running `spindump` then `cat /tmp/spindump.txt | grep "Fan speed"` will show it, but that's very slow and processor intensive. I would like a faster and more efficient way of doing it.

I'd rather not install 3rd party software, but I will if it's the only way.

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I might accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Point is, as of Mavericks, Apple does not provide a way to query SMC-managed information. Thus, best way would to use smcFanControl, which actually is way more than just a fac control.

Comment: I do use smcFanControl, but is there any way of accessing its information from terminal? That's what I'm most interested in.

Comment: You can use smcFanControl's `smc` command line tool to get the fan speed; https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/tree/master/smc-command

Comment: You are almost there. spindump has a manpage (`man spindump`) and you can set the time it needs to run. Answer is below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get the CPU temperature and fan speed from the command line in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## smcFanControl

You mention in your comments having [smcFanControl](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl) installed; this open source project includes the command line tool `smc`. You can use `smc` to get fan speed information via Terminal.app:

```
smc -f
```

See the [smc manual page](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/tree/master/smc-command) for more options.

Since Mac OS X 10.5, you need to use a third party piece of software to access the fan speed information. It appears no tool, installed by default on OS X, exposes this information through the terminal.

The open source project [Fan Control](https://bitbucket.org/elventear/fan-control/src) includes a command line tool that provides fan speed information. This article, [OS X: Current CPU temperature on command line](http://mrmekon.tumblr.com/post/18514303388/os-x-current-cpu-temperature-on-command-line), talks about the project and how to extract the fan speed:

```
smc -k TC0D -r | sed 's/.*bytes \(.*\))/\1/' |sed 's/\([0-9a-fA-F]*\)/0x\1/g' | perl -ne 'chomp; ($low,$high) = split(/ /); print (((hex($low)*256)+hex($high))/4/64); print "C\n";'
```

### Avoid spindump

`spindump` requires administrator privileges and when run manually, [spindump](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/spindump.8.html) samples user and kernel stacks for every process in the system. This is a computationally expensive process, even when run for one second.

### Alternatives

Other tools and applications exist, including [Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html). See [Can I get the CPU temperature and fan speed from the command line in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x)

### Pre-Mac OS X 10.5

This article, [get sensor information](http://www.cminow.org/ioreg_perl.html), shows how to use `ioreg` to extract the fan speed information with:

```
ioreg -c IOHWSensor | grep -B3 -A11 '"type" = "fanspeed"'
```

The above article and the script it contains was designed for Mac OS X 10.4.3.

See also:

- [Reading hardware information from command line with built-in tools.](http://www.reddit.com/r/osxterminal/comments/12cgc0/reading_hardware_information_from_command_line/)
- [Determining Fan Speeds](https://discussions.apple.com/message/1824758#1824758)

Comment: Bresink's Temperature Monitor (which I use) is free for reading temperature, but needs a license to read other sensors (e.g. fan speed).

Comment: It is good, but works only via command line, to find application go to: `cd /Applications/smcFanControl.app/Contents/Resources/`

Comment: `brew install Caskroom/cask/smcfancontrol` and using it also requires password.

Answer (score 36):

On Mojave, spindump doesn't seem to list the fan speed. Noticed that powermetrics does, though. Try running `sudo powermetrics -i 200 --samplers smc | grep Fan` instead.

Comment: I just tried, but didn't get any output regarding fan speed, also the man page doesn't indicate anything. How exactly does this work on your Mac?

Comment: powermetrics does take a few seconds to generate the fan speed, so let it run until it samples the SMC.  In the man page for powermetrics on 10.14.4, I see the following under the Output description section: "SMC: The smc sampler displays information supplied by the System Management Controller. On supported platforms, this includes fan speed and information from various temperature sensors." My system is a 2018 MacBookPro15,1.

Comment: Ah, for whatever reason it fails to read SMC values on my Mac Mini (`unable to get smc values`).

Comment: `sudo powermetrics -i 1 -n 1 --samplers smc` for a faster result. By default, powermetrics has a 5 second delay/interval.

Comment: This worked for me on a MacBookPro11,5 running Yosemite, as well.  Got fan speed, as well as temperatures for both CPU and GPU.

Comment: "unable to get smc values" on MacBookPro9,2 running 10.14.6.

Answer (score 8):

**Oneliner** - gives output after 1 second using spindump

```
SD=~/.spindump.txt;sudo rm $SD;sudo spindump 1 1 -file "$SD" ;grep "Fan speed" $SD
```

---

Each seperate part explained:

`SD=~/.spindump.txt`: create a variable with the .spindump.txt log

`sudo rm $SD`: clean up your tmp file using sudo rights, as the file was created by sudo spindump.

`sudo spindump 1 1 -file $SD`: run spindump as root (it only runs as root) for 1 second in 1 interval and output the file to your $SD

`grep "Fan speed" $SD`: get the line that says "Fan speed"

It is very unfortunate that we need sudo rights to run this script.

---

```
> SD=~/.spindump.txt;sudo rm $SD;sudo spindump 1 1 -file "$SD" ;grep "Fan speed" $SD

Password:
Sampling all processes for 1 seconds with 10 milliseconds of run time between samples
Focusing on launchd [1]
Sampling completed, processing symbols...
Spindump analysis written to file /Users/CousinCocaine/.spindump.txt
Fan speed:       2302 rpm
```

Comment: I'm running 10.8.5 on an iMac and my spindump report doesn't include any mention of "Fan speed" or even "fan".

Comment: I am running 10.9.1. I cannot find my 'version' of spindump, but my fan speed is in the first 20 lines.

Comment: are you on a laptop or desktop?

Comment: @aaaidan I am running a Mac Mini (Hardware model: Macmini5,3) and an MBP retina (Hardware model: MacBookPro11,1). Both have the variable "Fan speed" in their output.

Comment: Not finding this reliable. on my Macbook I have to take out the Touch part for it to work but then the rm does not work. Also if I run: `sudo spindump 1 1 -file /tmp/spindump.txt > /dev/null 2>&1;grep "Fan speed" /tmp/spindump.txt` One try it works next try it does not

Comment: @markhunte, I had the same issues. I hope my last update fixes your problem.

Comment: It did fix it cheers. Shame there does not seem to be a way to pipe the stdout from spindump to stdin

Comment: I don't see the "Fan speed" string either. OS X 10.6 on an iMac.

Comment: Incidentally, I want the fan speed because at times the fan is getting loud...

Comment: @Michael, for you http://www.eidac.de might work: smcFanControl

Answer (score 6):

Try `sudo powermetrics -s smc`. To change the refresh rate, use `sudo powermetrics -s smc -i <milliseconds>`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `powermetrics` built-in tool, asking for a single sample (`-i 1 -n 1`) for a fast answer.

```
$ sudo powermetrics -i 1 -n 1 --samplers smc | grep ^Fan
Fan: 2987 rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a MBA with SMC problems and this app solve my issue. The smcFanControl doesn't work for me and I've tryed FanControl too.
In GNU/Linux I can set the max and min values thru terminal so if I can in GNU/Linux, I have to do the same in a Unix system.
This app is Macs Fan Control
https://github.com/crystalidea/macs-fan-control/releases/download/v1.4.12/macsfancontrol.zip

I hope work for you too

Answer (score -5):

Triple click the following, copy it, and paste it into Terminal:

```
sudo spindump 1 1 -file /tmp/spindump.txt > /dev/null 2>&1;grep "Fan speed" /tmp/spindump.txt;sudo rm /tmp/spindump.txt
```

It should output the fan speed.

Comment: In the question, he says he does not want to do this exact thing.

Comment: Plus the question was answered fully last year.

Comment: I'd like to add my voice to @Spotlight's.

Comment: @Greg - Welcome to Ask Different.   The community *can* seem be a bit brutal here at times which may be a bit off putting for new users such as yourself.  I applaud your effort to contribute and wanted to point you toward our [Help Center:  How to Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as a resource for writing answers which will attract views and up votes.  Don't let the negative votes on your first answer dissuade you from contributing in the future.