# Get fan speed from terminal without spindump or third party software

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra

I was wondering if there was a way to access the computer fan speed through terminal. I've heard that you can use software like smcFanControl, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without any third party software.

Another way i've heard of is using the spindump command, but from what I remember it can take a bit for it to finish.

Is there a way to get the info from terminal almost instantly without using third party software?

Also, is there a command I could possibly use to adjust the fan speed using terminal without any third party software?

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2015 running macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Should we get your post linked with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117391/using-terminal-to-get-current-fan-speed? ? (I guess not since you just dropped a bounty on this) It would be nice to `pmset -g something` to get that with other thermal status for sure.

Comment: I'm curious as to what your aversion to 3rd party software is.

Comment: @JMY1000 I don’t have an issue with 3rd party software, I mostly want to know if they’re any built in ways to get and set the fan speed

Comment: AFAIK there's no built in utility, but at their core, they're just reading SMC data.

Answer (score 12):

macOS command **/usr/bin/powermetrics**

```
sudo powermetrics -i 200 -n1 --samplers smc
```

**output:**

```
**** SMC sensors ****

CPU Thermal level: 0
GPU Thermal level: 0
IO Thermal level: 0
Fan: 1199 rpm
CPU die temperature: 56.30 C
GPU die temperature: 79.00 C

sudo powermetrics -i 200 -n1 --samplers smc | grep "Fan" | sed 's/Fan: //g' # -> 1200 rpm
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use **smcFanControl** from the terminal. I written a complete script who analyse the temperature of the Mac to trigger an external fan with it (arduino).

```
alias smc="/Applications/smcFanControl.app/Contents/Resources/smc"
```

### List all

```
smc -l
```

### Get the temperature

```
smc -k TC0D -r
```

### List Fans

```
smc -f
```

More info on GitHub:  [smcFanControl: smc-command](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl/tree/master/smc-command)

Comment: smcFanControl is a third party software, and in the question I said a way that is fast and doesn't use a third party software.

Comment: Effectively, but your question is ambiguous (use the terminal without third-party software), precise that you want to get the info with a built-in or native macOS command, that I think is not possible, even less with the system integrity protection. As I know, the smc program is the faster (and only?) way to read and write to the SMC.

Comment: If SMCFanControl can read and write SMC settings, then anyone who knows how can do so as well.