# How to view real time dynamically updated information on thermals and fan speed through the terminal?

Tags: terminal, catalina, homebrew, python, system-information

Is there any way to view real time fan speed and thermal information (CPU, GPU) through the terminal, such as by installing an application with `homebrew` (i.e. `$ brew install ...`) or `python` (i.e. `$ pip install ...`)?

I found the threads below:

[Using terminal to get current fan speed?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117391/using-terminal-to-get-current-fan-speed)

[Can I get the CPU temperature and fan speed from the command line in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x)

However the suggestions for terminal applications (such as `istats`) only give static information (not real time dynamically update information).

There is a github repo called `lm-sensors` which was designed for linux, however this repo has not been updated in a while and I was not able to install it properly after cloning the git. After I run the Make file, I get errors about header files being missing.

I am running OS X 10.15.4 (Catalina).

Comment: You weren’t able to install *lm-sensors* for Linux on your Mac because macOS ≠ Linux.  Just because you have the source doest mean it’s just a compile away from getting a Mac version.

Comment: @Allan I realize that macOS is not Linux, however macOS has Darwin running as part of itsthe core components and Darwin is unix-like (and is based on free BSD). Numerous applications which are designed to run on linux will run on Darwin, that's the reason I gave `lm-sensors` a try.

Comment: Um, no.  Darwin is based on the Mach kernel.  Darwin is  **not** Unix like, it’s actually a *certified* Unix.  Apps/utilities designed for Linux don't “also run on Darwin”.  You’re confusing “made for Linux” and “the GNU version.”  If something is designed for  Linux  means it requires the Linux kernel and/or libraries.

Comment: @Allan I learned something today. This explains a lot.Thank you for the information and clearing my misconceptions.

Answer (score 2):

This Github repo has a [program that can provide CPU temperature and fan speed](https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp) on macOS and may be useful to you. If it only displays the readings one time, when you run it, just use the [watch command](https://shapeshed.com/unix-watch/) to run it continously. (You can install `watch` using MacPorts or Homebrew).

---

With regards to CPU temperature and power monitoring:

If you have an intel based Apple Mac, the [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-power-gadget.html) is a very useful application in getting accurate cpu core, temperature and power usage information.

While Intel Power Gadgets is a GUI based app it also includes a **command line tool** called **`PowerLog`**. (You can find PowerLog in *Intel Power Gadget* folder in *Applications*, after you install the Intel Power Gadget App).

Intel PowerLog doesn't display the information in realtime in the terminal, when run, but produces a log file. But you can use the [unix tail command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm) to view the log while it is being generated and thus get the output in realtime.

If you know how to code, Intel also provides an `Intel Power Gadget API` that you can use to [create your own cpu monitoring program](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/using-the-intel-power-gadget-api-on-mac-os-x.html).

---

The app [Mac Fans Control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) provides realtime infromation on cpu fan speed and temperature:

[image: Realtime CPU Fan Speed and Temperature]

If you are willing to pay for their software, contact them and ask if they can provide a command line version of the same app.