# How to get the temperature of MacBook hardware without extra software?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

We can use iStat Menus and other software.

Is it possible to get the temperature of MacBook hardware components without extra software? To use only programs already installed/delivered with MBP?

Comment: Have you searched this site? : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x

Comment: @SolarMike thank you, I haven't found this question before. Its about command line, which I would like to avoid if possible. The answers contain also deprecated software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be no discernable way to find the temperature of hardware components purely without 3rd party software.

Reference:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/12919985#message12919985

Comment: I;m guessing this is right. The API aren’t around to easily script this. Now - there always is a python script that basically uses the objectiveC bridge to basically re-implement the third party apps that read the raw data and recreate temperature values from the built in sensors.

Comment: What about nowadays 5 years later?

Comment: No change @theonlygusti   Feel free to drop a bounty on the linked questions if you think someone’s missing the boat. Hit us up on [chat] if needed to get a second “canonical” version of this alive if the normal process of editing and voting doesn’t work.